# How to fix 'Repository moved permanently to'? using VisualSVN / Subversion

Tags: windows-server-2003, svn, amazon-ec2, visualsvn-server

I'm using Visual SVN on a server.

Fresh install.  Create a new repository.  Try to connect using a client

it comes up with "Repository moved permanently to 'https://x.x.x.x:6443/'; please relocate"

I got a feeling it has to do with the IP address that clients use to connect is not the same as the one the server is running on?  not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message means that you are using invalid repository URL. VisualSVN Server repository url looks like http://servername/svn/repos/path. I recommend you to use Copy URL command in VisualSVN Server Manager to get right URL.

Comment: I had solved the problem already, but effectively this is the right answer for my problem... it was my bad....   I just had /svn     and was missing repository name.   Obscure error message for "Wrong URL Noddy"

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps you in resolving this problem.

http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#http-301-error

Answer (score 0):

try using svn switch to switch it to the IP address.

Comment: thats for switching the working copy?  there is no working copy yet as the error comes up when trying to connect to the server.  Or browsing the server.   You can however go in via the web interface and see the repository

Comment: Ah, my bad, for some reason I read the question as saying that it was an existing repo on a reinstall, and so I thought the client already had a connection.

Answer (score 0):

FYI:  I got this error when I had defined an alias to allow for listing of repositories:

```
Alias /svn "/var/svn/repos"

<Location /svn/>
  SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos
  SNVListParentPath on
  ....
</Location>
```

Without the Alias, I would get "Not Found" when browsing to /svn, whereas /svn/ would work.

So it seems a fix for one bug caused another one!

This problem is discussed in the link Critical Skill posted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try changing the `SVNParentPath` to `SVNPath` in your `httpd.conf` file. This is my configuration:

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath C:\svn_repository\proj1
</Location>
```

and works fine.

I'm checking the differences between `SVNPath` and `SVNParentPath`.